# Same model produces consistently different accuracies in Keras and Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to implement the same model in Keras, and in Tensorflow using Keras layers, using custom data. The two models produce consistently different accuracies over many times of training (keras ~71%, tensorflow ~65%). I want tensorflow to do as well as keras so I can go into the tensorflow iterations to tweak some lower level algorithms.

Here's my original Keras code:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Input 
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras import backend as K

input_size = 2000
num_classes = 4
num_industries = 22
num_aux_inputs = 3

main_input = Input(shape=(input_size,),name='text_vectors')
x = Dense(units=64, activation='relu', name = 'dense1')(main_input)
drop1 = Dropout(0.2,name='dropout1')(x)

auxiliary_input = Input(shape=(num_aux_inputs,), name='aux_input')
x = keras.layers.concatenate([drop1,auxiliary_input])
x = Dense(units=64, activation='relu',name='dense2')(x)
drop2 = Dropout(0.1,name='dropout2')(x)

x = Dense(units=32, activation='relu',name='dense3')(drop2)

main_output = Dense(units=num_classes, 
activation='softmax',name='main_output')(x)

model = Model(inputs=[main_input, auxiliary_input], 
outputs=main_output)

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics= ['accuracy'],optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta())

history = model.fit([train_x,train_x_auxiliary], train_y, batch_size=128, epochs=20, verbose=1, validation_data=([val_x,val_x_auxiliary], val_y))
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate([val_x,val_x_auxiliary], val_y, verbose=0)
```

Here's I moved the keras layers to tensorflow following [this article](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
import keras
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Input # Dense layers are "fully connected" layers
from keras.metrics import categorical_accuracy as accuracy
from keras.objectives import categorical_crossentropy


tf.reset_default_graph()

sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)

input_size = 2000
num_classes = 4
num_industries = 22
num_aux_inputs = 3

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, input_size], name='X')
x_aux = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_aux_inputs], name='X_aux')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_classes], name='Y')

# build graph
layer = Dense(units=64, activation='relu', name = 'dense1')(x)
drop1 = Dropout(0.2,name='dropout1')(layer)
layer = keras.layers.concatenate([drop1,x_aux])
layer = Dense(units=64, activation='relu',name='dense2')(layer)
drop2 = Dropout(0.1,name='dropout2')(layer)
layer = Dense(units=32, activation='relu',name='dense3')(drop2)
output_logits = Dense(units=num_classes, activation='softmax',name='main_output')(layer)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(categorical_crossentropy(y, output_logits))
acc_value = tf.reduce_mean(accuracy(y, output_logits))

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(output_logits, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1), name='correct_pred')

optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate=1.0, rho=0.95,epsilon=tf.keras.backend.epsilon()).minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess.run(init)

epochs = 20             # Total number of training epochs
batch_size = 128        # Training batch size
display_freq = 300      # Frequency of displaying the training results
num_tr_iter = int(len(y_train) / batch_size)

with sess.as_default():

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        print('Training epoch: {}'.format(epoch + 1))
        # Randomly shuffle the training data at the beginning of each epoch 
        x_train, x_train_aux, y_train = randomize(x_train, x_train_auxiliary, y_train)

        for iteration in range(num_tr_iter):
            start = iteration * batch_size
            end = (iteration + 1) * batch_size
            x_batch, x_aux_batch, y_batch = get_next_batch(x_train, x_train_aux, y_train, start, end)

            # Run optimization op (backprop)
            feed_dict_batch = {x: x_batch, x_aux:x_aux_batch, y: y_batch,K.learning_phase(): 1}

            optimizer.run(feed_dict=feed_dict_batch)
```

I also implemented the whole model from scratch in tensorflow, but it also is a ~65% accuracy, so I decided to try this Keras-layers-within-TF set up to identify problems.

I've looked up posts on similar problems with Keras and Tensorflow, and have tried the following which didn't help in my case:

1. Keras's dropout layer is only active in the training phase, so I did the same in my tf code by setting `keras.backend.learning_phase()`.
2. Keras and Tensorflow have different variable initializations. I've tried initializing my weights in tensorflow these following 3 ways, which is supposed to be the same as Keras's weight initialization, but they also didn't affect the accuracies:

   ```
   initer = tf.glorot_uniform_initializer() 
   initer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer() 
   initer = tf.random_normal(shape) * (np.sqrt(2.0/(shape[0] + shape[1])))
   ```
3. The optimizer in the two versions are set to be exactly the same! Though it doesn't look like the accuracy depends on the optimizer - I tried using different optimizers in both keras and tf and the accuracies each converge to the same.

Help!

Comment: Would it be possible to provide reproducible code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is most probably the weight initialization problem. What I would suggest you to do is to initialize `keras` layers and before training get the layer weights and initialize `tf` layers with those values.

I have ran into that kind of problems and it solved problems for me but it was a long time ago and I don't know if they made those initializers the same. At that time tf and keras initializations were not the same obviously.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I tried but it still didn't work... I've also tried initializing both networks with functions that are supposed to be doing the same thing (keras.initializers.glorot_normal(seed=None) and tf.glorot_uniform_initializer() ), but the accuracies didn't change.

Answer (score -1):

I checked with initializers,seed, parameters and hyperparameters but accuracy is different.

I checked the code for Keras and they randomly shuffle the batch of images and then fed into the network, so this shuffling is different across different engines. So we need to figure out a way in which we can fed the same set of batch images to the network in order to get same accuracy